# How to store an ID field across domains with HTML / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web app that has a conversion tracking feature to determine if an activity "A" performed by a website visitor causes them to take action "B".

This conversion tracking works fine if the tracking is all on one domain.  Where it breaks is if that happens across two different domains.

This tracking is currently done by storing a 1visitorId1 in HTML5 `localStorage` (though the solution doesn't have to use `localStorage`).   Then I retrieve that `visitorId` from another domain... I just need a way to store a recoverable piece of data across two domains.

The conversion tracking is enabled via a JavaScript embed.  So my customers will take a JS code snippet and paste it into the page where they want to track the conversions.  This is where the problem arises, as I have no control over where they will be embedding this JS snippet.

I hope I've made the problem (and the needed solution clear), if I haven't please leave a comment.

Thanks all!  I really appreciate the help from everyone in the StackOverflow community, you guys are all awesome :)

Comment: Browser security is generally intended to prevent information from leaking between domains.

Comment: I had read something about being able to get the user's MAC address, but you may need to have signed code or something along those lines.  I'm not sure what the cost or steps would be to get a piece of code signed, but I would be open to solutions like that if they existed.  I figured I'd ask on here first to see if there's a "free" option

Answer (score 0):

If you have power over both websites, then it's fairly easy (but it might not be the best solution).

If the user is allowed to see the ID, then simply add a `GET` variable to your URL and redirect the user there. E.g: domain2.com?visitorId=1234

Check this out on reading the variable: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: I had considered this, but I don't think it'll be possible.  The "best" I can do is to use a get variable for a more broad term.  This is what I'm currently using, but it doesn't give me the fine-grained details I want.  Again, this is caused because I don't have full control over Domain B, only over Domain A

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will result, but you could try this:

Domain B is where you have created a cookie or localStorage

From HTML in Domain A you will have an iframe pointing to some HTML page of Domain B, wich will be in charge of retrieving the desired cookie.

Then, you could use a postMessage library (like described in here: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/) to communicate iframe and your current page.

In that way you could have a listener in Domain A to listen for a function on Domain B where you will be passing the cookie or localStorage data.

Hope this aproach helps you. I repeat this is a suggestion. I have worked with postMessage and it works great!

Comment: Hmmm, this seems like an interesting suggestion... could I use jQuery to accomplish this postMessage?  Or do I have to use the library that's explain in your article?

Comment: Well, the library link that I have left it's the one that I have used on some project, but I just googled and there are libraries in jQuery too, for example: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Post message it's an HTML5 new functionality, but also a technique for supporting backwards compatibility on older browsers